# How to do fourier transform on $xe^{-|x|}$

Tags: fourier-transform

How do I solve this:

Newest image:
[After i corrected myself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euAsL.png)

> Compute the Fourier transform of
> $$f(x)=xe^{-|x|}$$

My answer is not correct:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{2\pi}\hat f(w)&=\int_0^\infty xe^{-x}e^{-iwx}\mathop{dx}+\int_{-\infty}^0 xe^xe^{-iwx}\mathop{dx}\\
&=\int_0^\infty xe^{-(1+iw)x}\mathop{dx}+\int_{-\infty}^0 xe^{-(1+iw)x}\mathop{dx}
\end{align*}

---

\begin{align*}
x&&&e^{(1-iw)x}\\
-1&&&-\frac{e^{(1-iw)x}}{1-iw}\\
0&&&\frac{e^{(1-iw)x}}{(1-iw)^2}
\end{align*}

---

\begin{align*}
\left[-\frac{xe^{-(1+iw)x}}{1+iw}-\frac{e^{-(1+iw)x}}{(1+iw)^2}\right]_0^\infty+\left[\frac{xe^{(1+iw)x}}{1+iw}-\frac{e^{(1+iw)x}}{(1+iw)^2}\right]_0^\infty&=\frac{1}{(1+iw)^2}-\frac{1}{(1-iw)^2}\\
&=\frac{(1-iw)^2-(1+iw)^2}{(1+iw)^2(1-iw)^2}\\
&=\frac{-4iw}{(1+iw)^2(1-iw)^2}\\
\implies \hat f(w)=\frac{-4iw}{\sqrt{2\pi}(1+iw)^2(1-iw)^2}
\end{align*}

Comment: You got the "trick" exactly right in the first step - now you just have to fix the details (which btw you can do as well as we can...) ("trick": $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(|t|)=\int_{-\infty}^0f(-t)+\int_0^\infty f(t)$.)

Comment: Aha so when i do absolute value of the x in the exponent, then de x under must become negative too. Thanks man, that helped alot. Soon exams in advanced engineering.

Comment: I still dont get it right @ David C. Ullrich

Answer (score 1):

I think that easiest is to use the fact that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f(x) e^{-iwx} \, dx
= i \frac{d}{dw} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{-iwx} \, dx.
$$

So first we calculate
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|} e^{-iwx} \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{x} e^{-iwx} \, dx
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x} e^{-iwx} \, dx
= \int_{-\infty}^{0} e^{(1-iw)x} \, dx
+ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{(-1-iw)x} \, dx
\\
= \left[ \frac{1}{1-iw} e^{(1-iw)x} \right]_{-\infty}^{0}
+ \left[ \frac{1}{-1-iw} e^{(-1-iw)x} \right]_{0}^{\infty}
= \frac{1}{1-iw}
- \frac{1}{-1-iw}
= \frac{2}{1+w^2}.
$$

Then we take the derivative:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x e^{-|x|} e^{-iwx} \, dx
= i \frac{d}{dw} \frac{2}{1+w^2}
= i \frac{4w}{(1+w^2)^2}.
$$

Thus,
$$
\hat{f}(w) = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{4w}{(1+w^2)^2}.
$$